# Cant' load cachex module

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to use cachex as a caching layer in my phoenix/elixir web app. When I open my interactive console iex, and type `Cachex.get(:my_cache, "key")`

it shows

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) function Cachex.get/2 is undefined (module Cachex is not available)
```

I followed all the steps as shown here https://github.com/whitfin/cachex

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Did you start `iex` with `iex -S mix`?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you didn't run the application when opening up the console (the cachex documentation just says `iex`). You should actually start the console with `iex -S mix` to have your application code.